# Python parse string environment variables

Tags: python, parsing, environment-variables

I would like to parse environment variables from a string.
For example:

```py
envs = parse_env('name="John Doe" age=21 gender=male')
print(envs)
# outputs: {"name": "John Doe", "age": 21, "gender": "male"}
```

What is the best and most minimalistic way to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the string?  The one in your example is not as easy to parse as it could be.

Comment: I guess I can drop the the quotes and would be easy because I don't think that there are going to have spaces inside the values. Just a bit ambitious. :P

Comment: Not having spaces within your values (or using escape sequences instead of quotes to denote spaces in values) makes it *much* easier.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can dictate that your values will never contain the special characters that you use in your input format (namely `=` and  ), this is very easy to do with `split`:

```
>>> def parse_env(envs):
...     pairs = [pair.split("=") for pair in envs.split(" ")]
...     return {var: val for var, val in pairs}
...
>>> parse_env("name=John_Doe age=21 gender=male")
{'name': 'John_Doe', 'age': '21', 'gender': 'male'}
```

If your special characters mean different things in different contexts (e.g. a `=` can be the separator between a var and value OR it can be part of a value), the problem is harder; you'll need to use some kind of state machine (e.g. a regex) to break the string into tokens in a way that takes into account the different ways that a character might be used in the string.

Comment: You can use maxsplit=1 to solve the problem: pair.split("=", maxsplit=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python Dotevn](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to parse a .env file with your variables. Your file `.env`
should be something like:

```
NAME="John Doe"
AGE=21
GENDER="male"
```

Then you should be able to run:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv    
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite what I was looking for. I appreciate your help.